# unbinding mouse scrolling with keyboard arrow keys on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, vim, key-bindings

I'm using vim on Ubuntu 16.04, my terminal is konsole.

The problem make me suffering is:
Everytime when I tried to paste something using the middle button of my mouse in vim, I got disturbed by accidentally scrolling the wheel of my mouse. The cursor flew away and I pasted the content on wrong place.

So I was tring to disable mouse scrolling in vim. However every solution I found online didn't seem to work to me. Finally I realized my <ScrollWheelUp/Down> was system-widely binded to arrow keys (↑ and ↓). By remapping arrowkeys to <nop>, mouse scrolling was disabled as well. So unless I unbind this, I cound't disable mouse scrolling in vim.

Unfortunately I didn't find any solution to do it. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found the solution.
I'm posting my solution here in case someone have the same issue with me:

**It seems that the only way to unbind <ScrollWheelUp/Down> to keyboard <Up/Down> is to re-compile your terminal. Because in most cases, the binding is hard coded.**

In my case, I use konsole as my terminal. So what I have done was to:
1. git clone the konsole source code by
                   `git clone git://anongit.kde.org/konsole.git`
2. In the source file 
                   `konsole/src/TerminalDisplay.cpp`
there is a piece of code between line 2501 and 2522:

```
    if (_mouseMarks) {
       const bool canScroll = _scrollBar->maximum() > 0;
       if (canScroll) {
           _scrollBar->event(ev);
           _sessionController->setSearchStartToWindowCurrentLine();
           _scrollWheelState.clearAll();
       }
       else {
        // assume that each Up / Down key event will cause the terminal application
        // to scroll by one line.
        //
        // to get a reasonable scrolling speed, scroll by one line for every 5 degrees
        // of mouse wheel rotation.  Mouse wheels typically move in steps of 15 degrees,
        // giving a scroll of 3 lines

        const int lines = _scrollWheelState.consumeSteps(static_cast<int>(_fontHeight * qApp->devicePixelRatio()), ScrollState::degreesToAngle(5));
        const int keyCode = lines > 0 ? Qt::Key_Up : Qt::Key_Down;
        QKeyEvent keyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, keyCode, Qt::NoModifier);

        for (int i = 0; i < abs(lines); i++)
            emit keyPressedSignal(&keyEvent);
       }
       ...
    }
```

comment the "else {**}" part to prevent konsole from binding wheel movement to arrow key pressing. 
3. recompile the source code package.
Restart you terminal then the issue would be gone.
If you use other terminal it should be pretty similar to get this done. **1) Download the source code package;2) modify the corresponding code; 3) re-compile ** That's it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to paste into Vim from somewhere else, I would recommend foregoing the mouse middle-click method and having Vim work directly with your system clipboard.  I think the below link should be of help:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard

Comment: Thank you for providing me other methods. However I think the most convenient method for myself is to use the middle button, because it's simple and fast. I've solved the wheel issue and I'm totally fine with what I have now. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

I think, you still can paste something into vim without using mouse at all. So, you don't need to setup anything to solve your problem.

Just put your vim cursor to the place that you want the text to be paste, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + v or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + v.

Comment: I'm sorry Ctrl + V or Cmd + V doesn't do pasting things in vim. There are keyboard shortcuts to paste content in linux terminal but it's not Ctrl + V or Cmd + V as what it is in Windows or OSX. And I'm not looking for a keyboard shortcut. I'm looking for a exact solution to make mouse middle button pasting works perfectly in vim. If you have experience in software developing on linux you should know what I mean.

Comment: Okay. But, IMHO you should consider to not using mouse at all when using vim. The true power of vim is in keyboard / key binding.